# Convert requests to Json in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I want to store several requests that comes from a form to single column as json. I know i can use [toJson](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json) but that's in case you returning data from database. In my case my data comes from a form like `$request->input('address_id');` and more.

```
//incoming data
array:8 [▼
  "address_id" => "3"
  "weight" => "3"
  "shipping_cost" => "9000"
]
```

> This data above is just sample (i have more inputs but let say i only need
>   to make JSON of this 3 inputs)

How can I do that?

Comment: [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode)?

Comment: @JonStirling yep :) Thanks

Answer (score 5):

you can convert your form fields into json like

json_encode($request->all());

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use the php function [json encode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) like this:

```
json_encode($request->input('address_id'));
```